# How to write a XML file to S3 Using Amazon Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have my code below which works well and creates a xml file in my local machine. But, I want to run this function in lambda to write a XML file to a folder in s3 bucket, what modifications do I have to make or atleast suggest me an ideology to make that happen? I'm very new to AWS services any help will be appreciated!

```
import pymysql
     def query_db(outfileName):
outfile = file(outfileName, 'w')
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host='XXXXXX',
    user='XXXXXX',
    password='XXXXX',
    database='XXXXX',
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select title from table1;")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
outfile.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n')
outfile.write('<source>\n')
for row in rows:
    outfile.write('  <job>\n')
    outfile.write('    <title><![CDATA[%s]]></title>\n' % row[0]) 
    outfile.write('  </job>\n')
outfile.write('</source>\n')
outfile.close()
query_db('data.xml')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the AWS SDK (Boto3). Write the file to the `/tmp` directory (the only place you can write files in Lambda). After you finish writing the file, call the AWS SDK to copy the file to your S3 bucket.

Alternatively, you could look into streaming the XML file contents to S3, but that would require more code changes.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested it still shows the error as  "IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '\tmp\\data.xml'

Comment: My bad It works ! huhu I put the slashes in other way before